# Go language strange behavior by handling templates

Tags: templates, go

[go](/questions/tagged/go)[templates](/questions/tagged/templates)
Hello!

I'm learning Go language now and trying to port some simple WEB code (Laravel 4).
Everything was well, until I tried to reproduce Blade templates into text templates. 
I found that Go can load my CSS and JavaScript files only from the catalog with a name **"bootstrap"** only.

Here is my catalog tree which I tried to use:

```
start-catalog
  bootstrap (link to bootstrap-3.3.1)
      bootstrap-3.3.1
    css
      bootstrap.min.css
    js
      bootstrap.min.js
  jquery
    jquery (link to jquery-2.1.1.min.js) 
    jsquery-2.1.1.min.js
  go_prg.go

Here are my templates:
```

base_js.tmpl

```
{{define "base_js"}}
      {{template "login_1"}}

      <script src = "/bootstrap/js/jquery"></script>
      <script src = "/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{{end}}
```

base_header.tmpl

`{{define "base_header"}}

<head>
    <title>PAGE TITLE</title>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href = "/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
</head> 

{{end}}`

If the catalog name differs from "bootstrap" Go language or Firefox can't load files from the templates above: **bootstrap.min.css**, **bootstrap.min.js**, **jquery**.
If I use not the link but the catalog name directly "bootstrap-3.3.1" than Go or Firefox can't load.
If all required files are moved under "bootstrap" I'm getting the results I expected (exactly the same as in Laravel 4).

To launch go language code the command **go run go_prg.go** was used.
Environment: Ubuntu 14.04, go-1.3.3, Firefox 31.

Who's wrong: Go language, Firefox or me?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Where's the Go code that's causing you problems?

Comment: @Greg,There is no problem in Go code but in use of a catalog of files. If all files resides in bootstrap catalog results are as expected, if not - the browser is not able to find required files.

Comment: please post your go code where you load the static directory. it seems is a path problem

Comment: @greg   Sorry, you were right the problem is in me and my code (see main function). I didn't pay attention to http.Handle():   func main() {
 flag.Parse()

 http.Handle("/bootstrap/", http.StripPrefix("/bootstrap/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("bootstrap"))))

 http.HandleFunc("/fima/", rootHandler)

 if *addr {
  l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:0")
  if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
  }
  err = ioutil.WriteFile("final-port.txt", []byte(l.Addr().String()), 0644)
  if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
  }
  s := &http.Server{}
  s.Serve(l)
  return
 }

 http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)
}

Comment: Please accept my apologies as this is my 1st post and I don't know how to format comments.func main() {

 flag.Parse()

 http.Handle("/bootstrap/", http.StripPrefix("/bootstrap/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("bootstrap")))) // this line cause the problem described

 http.HandleFunc("/fima/", rootHandler) // this line handles the page

Answer (score 0):

The problem described was caused by

```
http.Handle("/bootstrap/", http.StripPrefix("/bootstrap/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("bootstrap"))))
```

before any template was handled. It allowed access files under the directory 'bootstrap' only.

The problem was fixed by changing to
http.Handle( , http.StripPrefix(, http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))))
and adding  to pathes for CSS and JavaScript files. Like so

/bootstrap/js/jquery">.